# Slack - How does it handle multiple workspaces associated with a user

Tags: c#, .net, slack

I'm in the process of building an application, this application will allow for a user to sign up and create multiple locations (look at it as a business with multiple locations) these locations are to be treated as their own separate entity.

I was looking through the web to try and find some information on how Slack handles it's workspaces. As the approach here would be very similar eg, user signs in, then can either login to a workspace and switch to a workspace they're already logged into.

The way I was going to tackle this would be

1. Create a Location table
2. Create a UserLocation Table (link between user and location)
3. Create a User Table

User signs in, he/she will then be shown all locations associated with them, they can then either login to a location or sign out of a location and at any point they could be signed into all locations, very much like Slack and it's workspaces. Question is, how do I handle the authentication allowing a user to sign into a location, because they would have already signed to the application beforehand.

If this question isn't allowed on Stackoverflow, please let me know what child site of Stackoverflow should I post it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with authentication to the location - you authenticate as a user and you authorize access to a location. A user is already signed it - that's authentication. 
Therefor it has 0 or more locations (workspaces) right? But who decides which locations are eligible for the user (authorization)? When I use slack and want to add a member to my workspace I just authorize the user to be able to work in my workspace thus creating the UserLocation entry.

Comment: Well at the moment the user will sign up and create a location(s), you're correct with what you mentioned about authenticate as a user. When it comes to deciding who is eligible for a location etc, the person who created the location in the first instant will be the one who invites users to their location. If we look at slack, when you sign in you can switch between workspaces, if you logout of one of those workspaces you'd then be required to log back in when you try to access it again, however you're still logged in to your main account.  That's the functionality I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: That's the difference between authentication and authorization see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link.  I'm just wondering what the best way to handle this from a backend perspective.